# Encoding emoji in Erlang

Tags: unicode, erlang, emoji

Assuming I have a binary

```
Message = <<"string containing emoji">>.
```

How do I properly encode it in Unicode? I tried doing:

```
Encoded = <<Message/utf16>>.
```

I get this warning when compiling the file:

> Warning: binary construction will fail with a 'badarg' exception
>   (invalid Unicode code point in a utf8/utf16/utf32 segment)

I tried this with /utf8 as well. Same warning.

Comment: please see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668647/erlang-emysql-iphone-emoji-encoding-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the binary you start with is encoded according to UTF-8, and you need to encode it as little-endian UTF-16, this should work:

```
unicode:characters_to_binary(<<"string containing emoji">>, utf8, {utf16, little})
```

See [the documentation for the Unicode module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) for more information.

The reason why `<<Message/utf16>>` fails is that the `utf8`, `utf16` and `utf32` specifiers in bit syntax encode *a single codepoint*, not an entire string.  So to encode the character `U+1F64C`, you could use:

```
2> <<16#1f64c/utf8>>.
<<240,159,153,140>>
3> <<16#1f64c/utf16>>.
<<"\330=\336L">>
4> <<16#1f64c/utf32>>.
<<0,1,246,76>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `-*- coding: utf8 -*-` as the first line of your module, and use /utf8.

My guess is that you are using Erlang/OTP < 17, meaning files are considered latin-1 unless specified otherwise.