# Emoji Encoding and Decoding erlang from list to binary

Tags: erlang, mochiweb, jsonparser, jiffy, emq

I want this string to be parsed for VOIP Notification for iOS to binary string:

```
"{\"data\":{\"text\":\"❤️\"}}"
```

I expected the data printed on the Erlang shell to be:

```
<<"{\"data\":{\"text\":\"❤️\"}}">>
```

But when printed it shows:

```
{"data",[{"text",[10084,65039]}]}
```

I tried the solution from [Encoding emoji in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188529/encoding-emoji-in-erlang) but it just gives me a bit string of the emoji which is:

```
{<<"data">>,{[{<<"text">>,<<100,39,15,254>>}]}}
```

How do I properly show it in Unicode in the Erlang shell?

Comment: It looks like it is encoded correctly. Are you saying it's not encoded correctly or it's not displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you provide it is properly encoded, but it is not properly displayed. When you define strings using double quotes the string is actually stored as a list of character codes. In the case of the heart emoji `[10084,65039]` are the character codes. The Erlang shell isn't printing out the emoji itself, but rather the values of the bytes that represent the emoji.

In the second case, a binary string, you shouldn't need to do any special encoding of the binary, but you will need to tell Erlang to treat it as a UTF8 string. You can do that by specifying `/utf8` at the end before the closing `>>`:

```
<<"{\"data\":{\"text\":\"❤️\"}}"/utf8>>.
```

If you want to see the emoji stored in strings and binaries like these displayed in the shell as actual emoji and not character codes, you will need to use the `+pc` option when starting the shell so it treats all unicode characters as printable characters:

```
erl +pc unicode
```

Setting it to `unicode` will cause emoji printed in the shell like this:

[image: erlang erl shell emoji with unicode]

http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#id201195